# The method foo(T[]) in the type Class is not applicable for the arguments (Vector<Integer>)

Tags: java, generics

Can someone explain me what `T[]` does it mean? what can be accepted and why?

```
public class Class {

   public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int[] foo(T[] s) {
      // ...
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      int[] intArray1 = new int[10];
      int[] ris = foo(intArray1);  // nope

      Vector<Integer> intArray2 = new Vector<Integer>(10);
      int[] ris = foo(intArray2);  // nope

      Integer[] intArray3 = new Integer[10];
      int[] ris = foo(intArray3);  // ok

   }

}
```

Comment: A `Vector<Integer>` and an array are two different classes. They are not interchangeable. An `int[]` and `Integer[]` arrays are also not interchangeable.

Comment: To add to that the used type can't be a primitive and thus why the first version doesn't work.

Comment: Generics allow you to create a single method that is customized to whatever type you're working with. T is substituted for whatever this method is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`T[]` is an array of `T`s. Just like how a `String[]` is an array of `String`s.

The method signature: `public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int[] foo(T[] s)` means that:

- The method takes an array of `T`
- T extends Comparable
- the method returns an `int[]`

In short, this means that: when getting objects from your array, you know you can call `.compare()` on them, and that it will return an `int` in the standard `Comparable` format.

Comment: In general `T[]` will work with `Object[]` (assuming `T` is a type parameter). However, in this case, we are told `T extends Comparable<T>`, so `Object[]` will not work, since `Object` does not implement `Comparable`. However, `String[]`, `Integer[]` (not `int[]`), `Double[]`, etc will all work

Comment: Thank you, now I understand what you tried to say to me.